# How to start using GDAL and compile it by Dev-C++

Tags: gdal

I am new to GIS and I have a programming background but currently I am interested to develop a GIS software that can display a shapefile in a Windows form app. For the GUI part I use a Windows API and for the GIS part I want to use GDAL/OGR libraries.

I was reading and using the documentation of the GDAL site http://gdal.org/ogr_apitut.html and I try to use their example code, but when I compile it using Dev-C++ I can't complete the compilation properly.

From the above site I get this code:

```
   #include "ogrsf_frmts.h"
   #include"gdal_priv.h"
   #include"gdal.h"
   int main()
   {
    GDALAllRegister();
   }
```

When I compile the above code using Dev-C++ I get an error like the following:

undefined reference to OGRRegisterAll

Comment: have you tried to link against GDAL?

Comment: how can i do that please?

Comment: im afraid I dont have this exotic IDE handy to help further, smth like [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/dev-cpp/discussion/128327/thread/1baf9670/)

Comment: it doesn't fix the the error but i think it helps me to figure out the error and it was very help full thanks